# Making a richTextBox act like a console

Tags: c#, console, richtextbox

I'm coding an application and I want to have a console embedded in the form. I am using a richtextbox currently but that is not nessecary. I want to disable everything in the richtextbox like: Selection, deleting with del key and backspace, show a _ after every word I type. And have commands that are recognised when typed in and entered. Thanks alot! ~Layne~

Comment: Why not try to embed the console? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284500/embed-a-console-window-inside-a-wpf-window

Comment: because I dont want stock cmd commands. I want my own.

Comment: Try using the `SelectionProtected` method to protect everything above the line the use can type on.  Usually requires freezing the control in order to hide the massive flicker.

Comment: Is this now an answer or still a question?

Comment: I rolled it back to the original.  Answers go in the "Your Answer" box below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer. I created a listbox and a richtextbox. Textbox text (commands) get sent to the listbox.
Here is the code I am using.

```
private void richTextBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(richTextBox2.Text);



                if (richTextBox2.Text == a1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("-c can't be used as a raw command, it is used to define when another command is being used. Try -c r to run the game...");
                }
                else if (richTextBox2.Text == a2)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Arcanists.jar");

                }
                else if (richTextBox2.Text == a3)
                {
                    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process myProc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
                    {
                        if (myProc.ProcessName == "javaw")
                        {
                            myProc.Kill();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (richTextBox2.Text == a4)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Type -c r to run the game");
                }
                else
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add("*!Invalid Command!*");
                }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your clicks to focus to your text input via a text box. Your going to need a richtextbox for output and a text box for input like a video game with a console option

Comment: It's usually best to give a short example to demonstrate your solution.