# How to embed a external CLI window into a Panel in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, window, command-line-interface

In C# or VB.NET, under Windows Forms, I would like to know how can I embed a external command-line interface (CLI) window, into a panel or other kind of host window where I can render the contents of the external CLI window inside my form.

Please note that I don't pretend to redirect and print the *StdOut* stream by myself. I just would like to embed the window into my form and let it be.

I've tried [SetParent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359296/1248295) function as suggested, but it does not seem to work for non-graphical user-interface windows, because when setting the parent window, the CLI window disappear from screen and it is not rendered in the parent (a panel) window.

It seems this can be done in WPF as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284500/embed-a-console-window-inside-a-wpf-window), but I'm not aware how to do this under Windows Forms.

I'm looking for some workaround that I could use in a way like this:

```
using (var p = new Process()) {
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @".\cli-process.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"...";
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        p.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        EmbedToWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Panel1.Handle);
        p.WaitForExit(TimeOut.Infinite);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Unhook Window into its original State](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65847818/7444103) (works with cmd.exe, PowerShell UI)

Comment: BTW, read the linked blog post from Raymond Chen.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks. For some reason it is not working for me. I'm on a x64 process, using Get/SetWindowLongPtr,  and trying to embed the CLI window to my form handle. And when I get the window style of the CLI process (after I called SetParent function), it has already set the WS_STYLE flag. But the window is not shown. I also tried to use SetWindowPos as suggested but there is really no need because I'm running the form maximized while trying this. What I could be doing wrong?.

Comment: That code is tested with a WinForms app (.Net Framework 4.8), some random applications and, as mentioned, with Windows 7 and 10's CMD.exe and PowerShell (which, btw, I've re-tested right now and it works as intended) -- I don't know what Process you're testing and whether its `MainWindowHandle` is what you think it is. -- Get/SetWindowLongPtr is used to remove parts of the UI, you don't actually need that, but you need `SetWindowPos()` (assuming the handle of the Window is valid). -- That code reads `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`, so check the result.

Comment: Not sure was I was doing wrong when getting or setting the style, but I retested it and finally it worked. https://i.imgur.com/YFELv3U.png  - thanks a lot my friend, very helpful your help as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a simple helper class in VB.NET that will serve me to set and release a parent window with ease.

It seems to work as expected at least as far as I have tested it in my required scenarios.

Thanks to @Jimi, @RbMm and @Remy Lebeau for their help and their tips that I need to know in order to figure how to do this.

However, what I share here is not functional due to missing types, but you could get the idea. Sorry but it would require to exceed the maximum character limit of this post, and maybe it's too much effort of copy & paste and adapt things to show them here if I'm the only one interested to accomplish this task...

But if you want to figure how to make this class functional then simply add the missing P/Invoke members of which I use in the missing `NativeMethods` class definition, and replace the missing `WindowInfo` type for a call to [GetWindowInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowinfo) (and the **WINDOWINFO** struct) or else [GetClientRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclientrect) + [GetWindowLongPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptra) functions, and replace missing `SafeWindowHandle` type for `IntPtr` or for a custom class derived  from [SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandlezeroorminusoneisinvalid?view=net-6.0).

### Usage Example:

```
Dim process As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("name").Single()
Dim windowParenting As New WindowParenting(process.MainWindowHandle)

windowParenting.SetParent(Me.Panel1, 
                          fitToParentBounds:=True, 
                          removeBorder:=True, 
                          removeCaption:=True, 
                          resizable:=False)

Thread.Sleep(5000)
windowParenting.ReleaseParent(throwOnInvalidSourceWindowHandle:=True)

' Or...
' windowParenting.Dispose() ' It calls ReleaseParent.
```

### WindowParenting Class:

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Implements a mechanism to set and release the parent window for a specific source window.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Class WindowParenting : Implements IDisposable

#Region " Properties"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A safe handle to the source window.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property WindowHandle As SafeWindowHandle

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a <see cref="DevCase.Core.IPC.WindowInfo"/> object for the source window.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property WindowInfo As WindowInfo
        Get
            Return Me.GetWindowInfo()
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a value that determine whether the source window has a parent window.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property HasParent As Boolean
        Get
            Try
                Return Me.WindowInfo.ParentWindow IsNot Nothing
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return False
            End Try
        End Get
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " Private Fields"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Keeps track of the current source window bounds when making a call to <see cref="WindowParenting.SetParent"/> method.
    ''' </summary>
    Private lastBounds As Rectangle = Rectangle.Empty

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Keeps track of the current source <see cref="WindowStyles"/> when making a call to <see cref="WindowParenting.SetParent"/> method.
    ''' </summary>
    Private lastWindowStyle As WindowStyles = WindowStyles.None

#End Region

#Region " Constructors "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WindowParenting"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="hwnd">
    ''' A handle to the source window.
    ''' </param>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub New(hwnd As IntPtr)
        Me.New(New SafeWindowHandle(hwnd))
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WindowParenting"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="hwnd">
    ''' A handle to the source window.
    ''' </param>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub New(hwnd As SafeHandle)
        Me.WindowHandle = hwnd

        If Me.WindowHandle.IsInvalid Then
            Throw New Exception("Invalid window handle.")
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WindowParenting"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="window">
    ''' AThe source window.
    ''' </param>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub New(window As NativeWindow)
        Me.New(New SafeWindowHandle(window.Handle))
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WindowParenting"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="window">
    ''' The source window.
    ''' </param>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub New(window As IWin32Window)
        Me.New(New SafeWindowHandle(window.Handle))
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Public Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets a new parent window for the source window.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="parentWindow">
    ''' The parent window.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="fitToParentBounds">
    ''' If set to <see langword="True"/>, fits to size of the source window to the parent window bounds.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="removeBorder">
    ''' If set to <see langword="True"/>, removes the border from the source window.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="removeCaption">
    ''' If set to <see langword="True"/>, removes the caption from the source window.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="resizable">
    ''' If set to <see langword="False"/>, remove sthe size frame from the source window.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
    ''' Source window already has a parent window.
    ''' </exception>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Overridable Sub SetParent(parentWindow As IWin32Window, fitToParentBounds As Boolean,
                                     removeBorder As Boolean, removeCaption As Boolean,
                                     resizable As Boolean)

        Dim curentWindowInfo As WindowInfo = Me.GetWindowInfo()
        If Me.lastBounds = Rectangle.Empty Then
            Me.lastBounds = curentWindowInfo.Bounds
        End If
        If Me.lastWindowStyle = WindowStyles.None Then
            Me.lastWindowStyle = curentWindowInfo.WindowStyle
        End If

        Dim newStyle As WindowStyles = (Me.lastWindowStyle And Not WindowStyles.SysMenu)
        If removeBorder Then
            newStyle = (newStyle And Not WindowStyles.Border)
        End If
        If removeCaption Then
            newStyle = (newStyle And Not WindowStyles.Caption)
        End If
        If Not resizable Then
            newStyle = (newStyle And Not WindowStyles.SizeFrame)
        End If

        Dim parentWindowHandle As New SafeWindowHandle(parentWindow.Handle)

        NativeMethods.SetParent(Me.WindowHandle, parentWindowHandle)
        Me.SetSourceWindowStyle(newStyle)

        Dim parentClientRect As Rectangle
        If fitToParentBounds Then
            NativeMethods.GetClientRect(parentWindowHandle, parentClientRect)
        End If
        NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(Me.WindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0,
                                   If(fitToParentBounds, parentClientRect.Width, 0),
                                   If(fitToParentBounds, parentClientRect.Height, 0),
                                   SetWindowPosFlags.AsyncWindowPos Or
                                   SetWindowPosFlags.ShowWindow Or
                                   If(fitToParentBounds, SetWindowPosFlags.None, SetWindowPosFlags.IgnoreResize))

    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub SetParent(parentWindow As NativeWindow, fitToParentBounds As Boolean,
                                     removeBorder As Boolean, removeCaption As Boolean,
                                     resizable As Boolean)

        Me.SetParent(DirectCast(parentWindow, IWin32Window), fitToParentBounds, removeBorder, removeCaption, resizable)

    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub SetParent(parentWindow As Control, fitToParentBounds As Boolean,
                                     removeBorder As Boolean, removeCaption As Boolean,
                                     resizable As Boolean)

        Me.SetParent(DirectCast(parentWindow, IWin32Window), fitToParentBounds, removeBorder, removeCaption, resizable)

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Release the source window from its current parent window.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="throwOnInvalidSourceWindowHandle">
    ''' If set to <see langword="True"/>, throws an <see cref="NullReferenceException"/> 
    ''' if the source window handle specified in <see cref="WindowParenting.WindowHandle"/> is invalid.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' This can be useful if you need to detect whether the source window has been destroyed.
    ''' </param>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Overridable Sub ReleaseParent(Optional throwOnInvalidSourceWindowHandle As Boolean = False)

        Dim isInvalid As Boolean = Me.WindowHandle.IsInvalid OrElse
                                   Me.WindowHandle.IsClosed OrElse
                                   Not NativeMethods.IsWindow(Me.WindowHandle)

        If isInvalid AndAlso throwOnInvalidSourceWindowHandle Then
            Throw New NullReferenceException("Invalid source window handle.")

        ElseIf Not isInvalid Then
            If Not Me.HasParent Then
                Throw New InvalidOperationException("Source window has not a parent window.")
            End If

            NativeMethods.SetParent(Me.WindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero)

            If Me.lastWindowStyle <> WindowStyles.None Then
                Me.SetSourceWindowStyle(Me.lastWindowStyle)
                Me.lastWindowStyle = WindowStyles.None
            End If

            If Me.lastBounds <> Rectangle.Empty Then
                NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(Me.WindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero,
                                       Me.lastBounds.X, Me.lastBounds.Y,
                                       Me.lastBounds.Width, Me.lastBounds.Height,
                                       SetWindowPosFlags.AsyncWindowPos)
                Me.lastBounds = Rectangle.Empty
            End If

        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a <see cref="DevCase.Core.IPC.WindowInfo"/> object for the source window.
    ''' </summary>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Private Function GetWindowInfo() As WindowInfo
        Return New WindowInfo(Me.WindowHandle)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets the <see cref="WindowStyles"/> for the source window.
    ''' </summary>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Private Sub SetSourceWindowStyle(style As WindowStyles)

        If Environment.Is64BitProcess Then
            NativeMethods.SetWindowLongPtr(Me.WindowHandle, WindowLongValues.WindowStyle, style)
        Else
            NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(Me.WindowHandle, WindowLongValues.WindowStyle, style)
        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " IDisposable Implementation "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Flag to detect redundant calls.
    ''' </summary>
    Private disposedValue As Boolean

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Releases all the resources used by this instance.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="disposing">
    ''' <see langword="True"/> to release both managed and unmanaged resources; 
    ''' <see langword="False"/> to release only unmanaged resources.
    ''' </param>
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue AndAlso disposing Then
            Try
                Me.ReleaseParent()
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            Me.WindowHandle?.Close()
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Releases all the resources used by this instance.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Me.Dispose(True)
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

*It lacks a bit of win32 error-handling for P/invokes. And maybe other things could be improved.*