# VT100 Encoding in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, terminal, vt100

I have to communicate with another device, which uses VT100 Encoding, at the moment I use a RichTextBox for displaying the characters, but VT100 Encoding is different to ASCII / UTF8 etc.

Is there a way to display all the VT100 Characters correctly in a RichTextBox?
If not - is it somehow possible to use e.g. https://github.com/franck-gaspoz/AnsiVtConsole.NetCore in a Windows Forms App, and Display a VT100 Terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: This answer looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3223875/741136

Comment: What do you mean by "VT100 character"? Remembering my old days where I had used a physical VT100, the characters displayed were simply ASCII. There were 95 printable characters in total, and the character "encoding" is unrelated to the terminal emulation. What really is VT100 specific, is the interpretation of terminal control codes.

Comment: Hello!
Exactly, I almost mean the terminal control codes - the escape codes. I think there are some special Characters too, but that's not the main problem I think.
Have someone ever played with the AnsiVtConsole, and give me some hints if it's possible to implement this into a WinForms (or WPF) Application?